# Given 2D Matrix, Find the number of islands of connected 1s present in the matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a Matrix consisting of 0s and 1s. Find the number of islands of connected 1s present in the matrix.
Note: A 1 is said to be connected if it has another 1 around it (either of the 8 directions).

I have written code as mentioned below:

```
class Islands {

    // Function to find the number of island in the given list A
    // N, M: size of list row and column respectively
    static boolean isSafe(int i, int j, ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> visited, int R, int C,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A){
        return ((i>=0 && i<R) && (j>=0 && j<C) && (A.get(i).get(j)==1) && (!visited.get(i).get(j)));
    }
    static void BFS(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A,ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> visited,int x , int y){
        int[] x_pos = {-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1};
        int[] y_pos = {-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1};
        visited.get(x).add(y,true);
        for(int k=0;k<8;k++){
            if(isSafe(x+x_pos[k],y+y_pos[k],visited,A.size(),A.get(0).size(),A))
                BFS(A,visited,x+x_pos[k],y+y_pos[k]);
        }
    }
    
    static int findIslands(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A, int N, int M) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> visited = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            visited.add(i,new ArrayList<Boolean>(M));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
                visited.get(i).add(j,false);
            }
        }
        int num = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
                if((A.get(i).get(j)==1) && (!visited.get(i).get(j))){
                    BFS(A, visited,i,j);
                    num++;
                }
            }
        }
        return num;
        
    }
}
```

For TestCase

> **1 1** 0
>
> 0 0 **1**
>
> **1** 0 **1**

Its returning 3 instead of 2.

While debugging, I found visited array getting modified like this

true true false

false false true

false false ***true***

true true false

false false true

true false ***false***

true true false

false false true

true false ***true***

What I don't understand is which part of my code changing the value true to false(Highlighted one).
Please suggest.

Comment: `Its returning 3 instead of 2.` 3 is actually correct.

Comment: Also you are doing a DFS, not a BFS. Also, it would be much more readable if you could use a boolean[][] instead of an arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Class ArrayList<E>
>
> public void *add*(int index,
>                   E element)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that
>   position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one
>   to their indices).

[See the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-)

What happens is that in fact you *push* the values at the end, and go from

```
true true false

false false true

false false true
```

to

```
true true false

false false true

true false false true
```